# IE9 not switching to IE8 mode with X-UA-Compatible=IE=8

Tags: internet-explorer-9, x-ua-compatible

On a website which breaks using IE9 but works fine if it's in IE8 mode (tested it with the developer tools) I've added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` to the `<head>` section.

However, it still renders in IE9 mode and the IE9-incompatible JavaScripts (a very old jQuery version and a similarly old jquery ui draggable/droppable version which I can't simply upgrade for reasons that do not matter here) don't work.

Do you have any ideas what could be the reason for the meta tag not being honored? According to dev tools IE9 is still in IE9 mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several sources the IE uses to determine whether to switch to compatibility mode or not:

- a MS internal list with sites to
  display in CM
- setting to display ALL pages in CM
- Developer Tools override page settings
- ...

See this [official ms site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/cc817574.aspx), section "Controlling DefaultRendering"

Comment: Ah.. "before all other elements, except for the TITLE element and otherMETA elements" - that might be the culprit. There's a `link rel="shortcut icon"` before it. Going to test it and then accept your answer.